# how to install friendsofsymfony/user-bundle via composer?

Tags: symfony, composer-php

Today i started some test with Symfony2 but i don't understand exactly how to install a 3th party package friendsofsymfony/user-bundle

I have installad a new simple project called "prova" on

```
/public_html/prova
/public_html/prova/app
/public_html/prova/vendor
...
```

I have composer installed on

```
/var/www/composer.phar
/var/www/public_html
```

Reading the documentation i should download the package using

```
./composer.phar require friendsofsymfony/user-bundle
```

The download all the packages on

```
/var/www/vendor
```

My question is
Composer should create this /vendor directory on my project /var/www/public_html/prova/vendor and not on the location of composer.phar

How should enable this packahge inside my project "Prova" ?

**UPDATE**
moved composer.phar inside public_html/prova project and execute the "require" command but throw this error

```
[InvalidArgumentException]
The target directory "web" does not exist.

assets:install [--symlink] [--relative] [-h|--help] [-q|--quiet] [-  v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi] [-n|--no-interaction] [-s|--shell] [--process-isolation] [-e|--env ENV] [--no-debug] [--] <command> [<target>]

Content-type: text/html

Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::installAssets handling the symfony-scripts event terminated with an exception

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.

[RuntimeException]
An error occurred when executing the "'assets:install --symlink --relative
  '\''web'\'''" command:
Content-type: text/html

[InvalidArgumentException]
The target directory "web" does not exist.

  assets:install [--symlink] [--relative] [-h|--help] [-q|--quiet] [-v|v
  v|vvv|--verbose] [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi] [-n|--no-interaction]
  [-s|--shell] [--process-isolation] [-e|--env ENV] [--no-debug] [--]
  32m<command> [<target>]
 .
```

Comment: Are you sure that `web` folder is there ? `/var/www/public_html/prova/web` ?

Answer (score 5):

Just copy `composer.phar` inside your project directory `/public_html/prova` and execute it from there:

```
php composer.phar require friendsofsymfony/user-bundle
```

Otherwise, you can install composer globally (https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#globally) and to forget the `composer.phar` file forever:

```
composer require friendsofsymfony/user-bundle
```